# JS Select2 - Call function/bind event to upon reaching minimumInputLength

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-select2

I have a select2 multi-select drop down that currently executes an ajax call, just wondering if there is any way of calling a function/bind an event handler to the user inputting the minimumInputLength. Need to do this so that I can collate multiple ajax sources into one and then return that to the select for the user to choose from.

Cheers

```
//Below is current Ajax select2
$("#Element_ID").select2({
id: function (data) {
    return data.Title;
},
multiple: false,
minimumInputLength: 5,
quietMillis: 100,
ajax: { //Need to do 2 gets before returning function which is what the function will do
    url: Url,
    delay: 250,
    dataType: 'json',
    data: function (term, page, context) {
        var query = "";
        if (term) {
            query = "substringof('" + term.term + "', Title)";
        }
        return {
            "$filter": query,
            "$top": 100,
        };
    },
    params: {
        contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
        }
    },
    processResults: function (data, params) {
        params.page = params.page || 1;
        var select2Data = $.map(data.value, function (obj) {
            obj.id = obj.Title;
            obj.text = obj.Desc;
            return obj;
        });
        return {
            results: select2Data
        };
    },
    cache: true
},
width: '100%',
formatSelection: function (item) {
    return item.text
},
placeholder: "Please enter query ..."
});
```

Comment: Add code snippet. Preferably compilable/jsfiddle

Comment: Added current code snip, can't run it as it queries a Sharepoint list